# Jboss eap 6.1: Failed to start the service :Could not resolve a binding for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/

Tags: web-services, jboss

I am Developing a webservice using JAXWS @webserviceprovider notation. when i try to deploy this service into JBoss eap 6.1 i got an error that client supports SOap1.2 messages.
so i included the binding type to the service. but when i deploy this service to JBoss eap 6.1
I get this error
Could not resolve a binding for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/

logs:

```
[org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."cifapp.ear"."Test.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."cifapp.ear"."Test.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "Test.war" of deployment "cifapp.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
```

Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:67)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:536)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:116)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:128)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:350)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.createBindingInfo(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:258)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:143)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:453)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:333)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/ registered.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:338)
    ... 20 more

Please can someone help

Thanks

Comment: Even i am facing same issue, any updates on  this?

Answer (score 1):

**Just replaced the binding URL, Actually binding URL Represent the SOAP
Service Version**

```
@BindingType(value="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")
```

Above BindingType URL Replaced with

```
@BindingType(value = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")

OR

@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

**Detail:**

> The BindingType annotation is applied to an endpoint implementation
>   class. It specifies the binding to use when publishing an endpoint of
>   this type.
>
> The default binding for an endpoint is the SOAP 1.1/HTTP one

**SOAP 1.1/HTTP**

```
@BindingType(value = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")

OR

@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING)
```

[image]

**SOAP 1.2/HTTP**

```
@BindingType(value = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")

OR

@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't generate the wsdl dynamically